# How to set the location of the port with code？

Tags: matlab, position, port, block, simulink

In the description of Matlab help：
Flexible port placement in Simulink Editor lets you move ports by clicking and dragging the port along the block icon outline, and this way you can put ports on any side of a Subsystem block, including top and bottom. The Port location on the parent subsystem parameter does not have separate values for top or bottom. If you drag a port to a different location on the Subsystem block icon, the parameter value automatically changes to reflect the new placement:
Left — The port appears on the left or top side of the subsystem icon.
Right — The port appears on the right or bottom side of the subsystem icon.
[image]
How to use code to realize the function of changing port location?
For example, add a port dynamically and place it on the top of the icon.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of MATLAB you are using? This feature is relatively new to Simulink

Comment: matlab 2021b. Yes, you can manually drag and drop to move the port location, but I don't know how to implement it in code.

Comment: Found your question on the Mathworks website. I can't see any obvious way to move the ports programmatically. Do you have a Mathworks online account through which you could request tech support?

Comment: I have found the instruction to position the port to the left or right. set_param(gcb,'Side','Left'). But  the port cannot be placed  on the top or bottom of the icon programmatically .

Comment: With the mathworks tools, the graphical features often arrive before the programmatic method does. They might not have a method for doing it yet.